# Having binary products, terminal object, and equalizers implies having finite limits

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

The answers to [this questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3551869/if-mathscr-a-has-all-products-and-equalizers-then-it-has-all-limits) prove that if a category has all products and equalizers, then it has all limits. How to modify that proof to show that if a category has binary products, a terminal object, and equalizers, then it has finite limits? (This is exercise 5.1.38(b) from [Leinster](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf).)

At least, what the "set up" should be? The proof in the link heavily uses arbitrary products, and I don't see how to replace them with binary products plus terminal object. Does some "combination" of the terminal object and binary products give arbitrary products?

Answer (score 2):

You do exactly the same thing, but note that the products are indexed by objects/arrows of the indexing category, so if the latter is finite, so are the products.

Then you just prove that if you have binary products and a terminal objects, you have all finite products : this is enough for the first sentence to actually go through.